# Не могу создать виртуальный монитор linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, x11

Пользуясь [этой](https://mihanentalpo.me/2017/07/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE/) инструкцией пытаюсь добавить планшет, как дополнительный экран

**Ситуация**: Доходя до шага 5 (Включение дополнительного монитора), получаю ошибку

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Выяснил, что при использовании cinnamon (или что-то, что основано на gnome) нельзя подключиться к существующему отключенному порту. Нашел инструкции, где используются виртуальные выходы, написанные для драйверов intel. Попробовал и точно так же, и изменяя драйвера на свои (nvidia): у меня виртуальные выходы не появляются в выводе xrandr.

**Суть вопроса**: как можно создать виртуальные выходы через xrandr для последующего использования через x11vnc?

**ОС**: Mint 19 tara

**DE**: Cinnamon 3.8.9

**WM**: Muffin

**GPU**: GeForce GTX 780 Ti

**Вывод xrandr**:

```
 ~> xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   <...>  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     74.97*+  60.00    59.94    50.00  
   <...>
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
  Fake (0x2c8) 172.040MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2048 start 2176 end 2392 total 2736 skew    0 clock  62.88KHz
        v: height 1536 start 1537 end 1540 total 1572           clock  40.00Hz
```

Comment: а какую именно команду у себя запускаешь? и ради определённости, дрова закрытые?

Comment: `Выяснил, что при использовании cinnamon (или что-то, что основано на gnome) нельзя подключиться к существующему отключенному порту.` — это скорей всего не верно...

Comment: сдаётся мне, проприетаный драйвер nvidia не поддерживает такие ухищрения вообще... как вариант, можно заморочиться с dummy* драйвером, но ИМХО овчинка выделки не будет стоить... так что остаётся поднять только отдельный виртуальный X-сервер для планшета...

Comment: Да, драйвера закрытые.
Но я не смогу переносить окна через границы экрана, если создавать ещё одну сессию

Comment: да не сможешь... ещё как гипотетический вариант, который может сработать: создать отдельное устройство на основе `dummy`-драйвера и объединить его с основным через `RandR` или `xinerama`. Из минусов: не гибкая сложная конфигурация, отсутствие/проблемы с ускорением на dummy-части экрана или вообще.